# Adding year on the search results listing

Tags: feature-request

When I search on a topic, the listing result lacks the year of the question/answers so I think it is recent while it is (often for my topic) one or several years old, I loose time on this and sometimes I reactivate old items by mistake. Could be a cool thing to add the year, that way there would be no need to open the link and search for the last update date of the item.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an example of a search result where you have seen this?

Comment: Ugh, I find Stack Exchange's use of "fuzzy time" everywhere quite frustrating. That said, I don't see missing "year" labels anywhere but on content from within 12 months (also: annoying). A screenshot would be good.

Comment: You are right, the year is there. My brain didn't see those 10'13 as some day 10 of the year 2013 even with several close looks. I have to change my neurons. In France dates are never presented in that order. I think the whole year 30 July of 2013 could disambiguate the notation. There is room for it, the line is dedicated to the date.

Comment: Why Americans put the month before the date is a constant mystery.

Comment: for anything sort related this is actually quite good (if you have natural sorting).